# Retrive data in database with complex computation using DDD pattern

Tags: php, node.js, database, orm, domain-driven-design

I am experimenting building software using DDD pattern. I have no problem with creating and updating data.  When the user fill-up the forms, it will automatically handle by my domain if there is a business logic involve with it.

My problem is how can I retrieve the data if there is some complex logic involve upon retrieving it?
For instance, using DDD in order software with discounts,should I store the total data after my domain computation? or compute the discount when retrieving it the database?

Thanks for your explanation. (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DDD your database is an external concern (part of the infrastructure) and plays no role in your model. In fact, the database is usually abstracted out to an interface for your Domain to use in it's computations. You use the DB to simply store and hydrate models.

To answer your question: it depends on your UL.
For example: you might store the discounted value in the database if you needed to "save" an order and retrieve it in it's exact state at a later time. Or maybe your Domain and UL requires users to transfer totals. For example: a balance transfer Application that allows the Application to shave a percentage off the amount transferred (it may be called a service fee). In this case, the total after the service fee is subtracted is most likely going to be saved.

Most of the time though, it's better to compute your discount in the domain because your discount is a Domain concept.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation louis.If the computation is in my domain, then the domain is only triggered by the event, so it is ok to store the computed total in db? And just retrieve it?

Comment: It's only okay to store the computed total if that's part of your UL (requirements). Otherwise, computing it in your Domain from raw values is my recommendation.

Comment: I have a last concern, Louis the DDD can only be use in event triggered? like POST,PUT,DELETE? I try to search on the internet for how many months, I can only see that they use DDD logic when the user form is submitted. But when retrieving the data (GET) there is no logic involve, they just query it and display in the U.I.  That is the reason why I store computed total in the database. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: DDD is usually wrapped in a larger architecture. So, you can use DDD in Event Driven Architectures, REST, Reactive or even MVC and MVVM. DDD will not usually extend past your model. To deal with UI and end-to-end architectures, you need a methodology like MVC. The "M" in MVC is where you will apply your DDD Design principles. The retrieval of data and the form display are all part of the "V" and "C" concerns.

Comment: ohh okay2x, now I get it. For instance, laravel is a MVC pattern, the database is attach to the model. Now, in DDD you need to pull out the database and create a persistence layer AKA repository. In doing that the model becomes entity and only depends on business requirements. Unlike mvc , the model attach to database, entity is much flexible because you can add value object in it.Now computed total or not it doesn't  matter, as long as my business logic not connected to db or application .Is just a class model. Thank you so Louis, now its clear to me. (-

Comment: "The "M" in MVC is where you will apply your DDD Design principles." This is like a light bulb to me. Thanks again (-: